# Error Rendering Problems Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio and I have the following error when opening

**Rendering Problems**
The following classes could not be instantiated
`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (...)`

I have read several forums and tried with different versions , but the problem persists.

`Android Studio version: 2.0 beta 6`
`SDK: Android 6.0 API 23 revision 2`

I would be grateful if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the android-studio beta 6 is having issues rendering the FAB, properly. This doesn't mean that the build/run might fail, it's probably just a Studio/GUI bug.

For a start (if you need the gui and don't need the fab)
Click tab "text" (next to "design" on bottom) 
and delete the following code, to remove the rendering error:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

finally go back to design.

(Maybe you shouldn't use the studio's canary update channel and go into the stable one to avoid getting beta versions)

Hope this helps

Comment: Michael thanks for your help. I deleted that part of the code, and the error disappeared.
I'll consider not use the studio's canary update channel.

Answer (score 0):

```
open your build.gradle (Module: app) file and change the version 
buildToolsVersion "23.x.x" to buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" also change
the version of dependencies :-
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
         compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
than rebuild the project....
That's it. :)
```